# gtkfilechooser - how to replace all titles with a custom one

Tags: c++, filechooser, webkitgtk

I have a requirement to replace ALL instance of

```
GtkWidget* dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new(_("Upload File"), blah...
```

in /gtk/WebCoreSupport/ChromeClientGtk.cpp with:

```
GtkWidget* dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new(_("L:D_N:dialog_ID:dialog:RKB:true"), blah...
```

Short of rebuilding the whole of webkit I was wondering how I would go about JUST replacing this function/object. I did note  a couple of questions *similar* to this but no actual code solutions were offered in response.

Would I have to create a library that derives from this and LD_PRELOAD it?

This would be on linux arm.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I should attach to the "run-file-chooser" signal:

http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-run-file-chooser

This would allow me to craft all calls instantiated, even within embedded webpages, "after the fact" into the formatting outlined above.

Simpler than rebuilding webkit.